# Is there a UNIX-style triple click to select path in Terminal.app?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, mouse, unix

In Red Hat, if there is a path somewhere on my terminal window and I triple click it, the whole path is selected. I can then easily copy it using middle-click or a regular copy-paste.

This doesn't seem to work in Terminal.app, i.e. triple click selects the whole line which is most of the time useless.

Is there a way to change this behavior? Should I look into other terminal apps like iTerm?

Comment: Looks like this work in iTerm.app. Nice ! Any tip for Terminal.app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The shortcut for Terminal.app is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+doubleclick.

You might also be interested in the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to clear the screen
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to delete everything to the left of the cursor
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete everything to the right of the cursor
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to jump to the left end
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to jump to the right end

Comment: In Lion, it's  ⌘+doubleclick, but it opens Safari not copy the selected URL to the clipboard.

Comment: ⌘+K clears all saved lines. To clear the screen, use control+L.

Comment: @lhf I don't know what you mean. ⌘+doubleclick seems to do nothing in 10.7.4 for me. To select a path only ⌘+SHIFT+doubleclick works for me.

Comment: I'm on 10.7.4 too. If you ⌘+doubleclick at any point in a URL shown in Terminal, you open Safari with that URL. But I realize it's not what you want to do.

Comment: @lhf, ⌘-Double-Click opens URLs (and man-page references, and email addresses). Add the Shift modifier to perform selection without attempting to open URLs. NOTE: You must not already have text selected, otherwise it will treat it as “add/remove discontiguous words to/from the selection” (for comparison, try Command-Clicking and -Dragging to add discontiguous text to the selection).

Comment: Prior to Mac OS X Lion 10.7, ⌘-Double-Click merely added/removed a word to/from the selection (Double-Click selects words, Command-Click adds/removes noncontiguous text to the selection) and ⌘-Shift-Double-Click would either select a path or open a URL, depending on what you clicked on. In Lion and later, ⌘-Shift-Double-Click always means "select a path or URL" and ⌘-Double-Click means "open the URL, if there is one and there isn't any other text selected".

Answer (score 5):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, a better terminal program is probably [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/). This does allow for this kind of selection, even nicer, double clicking also automatically copies it to the clipboard as well!

Comment: Thanks @romeovs! I made the initial post on the iPhone, where there seems to be no way to get to the editing help.

Comment: iTerm2 is way better than Terminal.app. Having a process list with Kill-Button is priceless. No more Ctrl-C.